# Render a Django CMS Placeholder to variable in view

Tags: django, django-cms

I try to render a Django CMS Placeholder from a page to a variable, to return the rendered code as JSON.

So what I do is:

```
from cms.models.placeholdermodel import Placeholder
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page

def render(self, page_id, placeholder_slot, request):
    page = Page.objects.get(id=page_id)
    placeholder = page.placeholders.get(slot=placeholder_slot)
```

Now I want to render the placeholder to a variable. Which function do I have to call in which way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can render it using [`Placeholder.render`](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/7888ab8421bb836c8f7a1127d9a2bf4d4bbdf23e/cms/models/placeholdermodel.py#L131). Note that the context **must** contain a valid `HttpRequest` object under the `'request'` key. `width` may be `None`. See the [`{% render_placeholder %}` implementation](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/7888ab8421bb836c8f7a1127d9a2bf4d4bbdf23e/cms/templatetags/cms_tags.py#L1132) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The `Placeholder` can be called manually and rendered like that, a few examples:

```
from cms import models
from django import template

def render(request):
    placeholder = models.Placeholder.objects.get_or_create(slot='some_slot')
    context = template.RequestContext(request)
    return placeholder.render(request, width=None)
```

Or for json/javascript/etc. where you don't want full html but just the value:

```
def render_basic(request):
    placeholder = models.Placeholder.objects.get_or_create(slot='some_slot')
    context = template.RequestContext(request)
    return placeholder.render(request, width=None, editable=False)
```

It's also possible (and even easier) to use the `StaticPlaceholder`:

```
from cms import models

def render(request):
    placeholder = models.StaticPlaceholder.objects.get_or_create(name='name of the placeholder')
    return placeholder.code
```